# How can I wait for multiple promises to all be done before using their return data for another function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, ecmascript-5

Unless I'm mistaken, I would like to get the values from 3 different promises and use what they return to call a function.  I tried looking at chaining promises and Promise.all but I don't think that solves what I'm looking for?

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
somePromise( someParam ) => ( someReturnObj1 => {

});

somePromise2( someParam ) => ( someReturnObj2 => {

});

somePromise3( someParam ) => ( someReturnObj3 => {

});

// I would like to call this after getting all the data from those 3 promises
callSomeFunc( someReturnObj1, someReturnObj2, someReturnObj3 );
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @CoryKleiser I was looking into that, but maybe I didn't understand, but I didn't see how I could use that in my situation.  Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Generally, when a comment disappears that quickly, the individual is writing an answer or made a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Promise.all([promise1,promise2]).then(result => {
    resultFromPromise1 = result[0];
    resultFromPromise2 = result[1];
});
```

Comment: ah so i can use Promise.all... i guess i read the example incorrectly.  thank you will try this.